# Determining the capacitive reactance of a capacitor graphically

Tags: electric-circuits, experimental-physics, capacitance, computational-physics

I measured the voltage and current of an RC circuit with the frequency of $f=105 \;\text{Hz}$. I modified the current with a decade box and measured the voltages ten times. With these measurements I should determine graphically the capacitive reactance of a capacitor.

Below the scheme.

[image]

By utilising the LINREGR command on Google Spreadsheet I was able to determine the slope and the intercept point of the linear trend of the measurements, but how do I go forward from here? I can calculate the reactance at singular points with Ohm's law but that's not graphical determining they're looking for.

Below the measurements and the graph

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you told us everything what's going on?  With constant frequency $\omega = 2\pi f$, $Z=R+(j\omega C)^{-1}$ is also constant, so the dependence between magnitudes of current and voltage should be linear without offset $|U|=|I||Z|$. And according to your measurements the effective impedance varies a lot $|Z|(0.60) = 0.33$, $|Z|(0.85) = 1.15$

Comment: I modified the current by utilising a decade box, with the following values of R(Ω): 0, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 5000 and 7000

Comment: Please add a scheme to your question and mark where you measure the voltage and current

Comment: Added info on decade box and the scheme

Comment: Something ist strange about you measurements. with R=0 U ist the voltage of the source. Now the current with R=7000 Ohm should be less than 1/7 mA.

Comment: I know that the measurements are imperfect, but the question still stands: How does one graphically determine the capacitive reactance?

Comment: Who is "they"?  With a fixed frequency, the $X_c$ should be constant. How close do your meters come to being "ideal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For steady-state measurements (your case) the capacitive reactance, $X_C$, is the slope of your V-I plot (rise over run).  Measurement errors aside, it is that simple.

Assuming your voltage and current measurements are [rms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) values then your $X_C$ will be in $k\Omega$ since your current is in mA.